# Is it necessary to add prefixes of halogens to the IUPAC name alphabetically?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

If I draw the structures of 2-bromo-4-chloropentane and
4-chloro-2-bromopentane, I get the same result, when I try to draw the structures. So why is it necessary to name prefixes alphabetically? Can we write IUPAC names not alphabetically?

Comment: I think it's just a discipline.. nothing much.

Answer (score 2):

With the preferred IUPAC name (PIN), there is exactly one way that you expect to find a compound written.

Assume you want to buy the compound from the chemical supplier of your choice but don’t have a CAS number at hand. What do you do? You search for the compound in the catalogue. In the old days, these were always paper books that you could use as a weapon but nowadays electronic catalogues exist too. Still, if you’re looking for 1-bromo-3-chloropentane but it is entered into the catalogue as 3-chloro-1-bromopentane, you’re going to have a very hard time searching for it.

There are also other reasons why having one defined standard way of naming compounds is strongly preferred over random but clear.

Comment: As side note to the OP, for some weeks now, [resources for learning chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry) includes a dedicated section «References about Nomenclature», too.

Comment: Anyway, it is always better to have only one name for a given substance. Chemists may realize that 2-bromo-4-chloropentane and 4-chloro-2-bromopentane are one and the same substance. But the clerk at the customs, the manager and the caretaker may not be able to do this reasoning.